# Rubyctaculous Gem in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, param, strong-parameters

On the offset - I am new to Rails, and struggling..

I am trying to implement https://github.com/basgys/rubyctaculous to my pins upload...

I have a scaffold where the image (or pin) is uploaded to Amazon S3, and a return URL is stored in the Rails database.

I then want it sent to Pictaculous (using the RubyGem mentioned) to grab the colour palette, which is stored in a "palette" column in my pins database to be read in the "show" view...

Using strong parameters of course...

I have added comments to the codes below.

First of all I have created this parameter at the bottom of my controller.rb:

```
def palette_find
  @pictaculous = Pictaculous::Client.new
  colors = pictaculous.color_palette_for_image(:image) #This would be the image path from Amazon S3 stored in :image
  puts colors.inspect
 => [:palette] #How do I put the returning data into palette column???
  end
end
```

(this is the part I have no idea what I'm doing)

I then want the parameter "palette_find" to activate during the "create" action in controller.rb after the "if @pin.save" which is where the database is updated with the image:

```
def create
@pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)
  if @pin.save

      #I would assume you'd need to add something here involving "palette_find" because you'd have to have S3 confirmation before pulling from the database.

if    #Then perhaps do the if ____ ensuring that "palette_find" worked.

  redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.'
else
  render action: 'new'
end
end
```

(Other info)

The correct_user param looks like:

```
def correct_user
  @pin = current_user.pins.find_by(id: params[:id])
  redirect_to pins_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this pin!" if @pin.nil?
end
```

And pin_params

```
def pin_params
  params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :image)
end
```

Might I also need something like palette_params?

```
def palette_params
  params.require(:pin).permit(:palette)
end
```

I hope someone can at least point me in the right direction...

Owen